# How to delete an additional character on the pyramid (CS50 Mario Program) formed by this code to be right aligned?

Tags: c, cs50

I'm currently taking CS50 course. At the very first assignment, I need to create a pyramid in C, using hashes (#) which allows the user to decide just how tall the pyramid should be by first prompting them for a positive integer between, say, 1 and 8. The expected output and the output that I receive as follows; [https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Qkg5.png]. I somehow managed to add one space on each row, does anyone have any idea to how to fix that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n;

    do 
    {
        n = get_int("Enter the height: ");
    }
    while (n<1 || n>8);

    for (int i = 1; i<=n; i++ )
    {
        for(int spaces = (n-i); spaces>=0 ;spaces--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(int dashes = 1; dashes<=i ; dashes++)
        {
            printf("#");
        }

            printf("\n");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider the case where `n == i`, which happens in the last row of the pyramid. The way you've written your for-loop, it will still run once, because `spaces` gets set to zero. But on the last row, you need no spaces, the for loop shouldn't even run once. The fix is simple: Change `spaces >= 0` to `spaces > 0`. That way the loop only runs exactly `spaces` times (which might be zero), and not `spaces+1` times like it is now.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. I just fixed the way you said and it works perfectly now! Thank you so much!